# javascript popup picker

Tags: asp.net

I have a grid with two columns: students name and it's grade, at a specific work, let's suppose.

The grade scope is between 0 and 20. Right now, it's being set trough a dropdownlist. However, I find this control kinda difficult, specially because we have to set many grades.

So, my question is: what other control would suit best? A textbox with a popup control, for example? A simple textbox?

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

You could just replace the dropdownlist with a textbox. Then have validators against that textbox so that the entered data only falls between 0-20

Comment: Thanks. I had that in mind also, but we're talking about people with difficulties when working with keyboard in a effective way. I thought about a kinda of datepicker, but with values from 0 to 20, I mean, when clicking in textbox, a small div with this values appear. How can I do this? Is it easy to change a datepicker example? With jQuery, for example...